# TypeScript parameter type inference failure

Tags: typescript, types, parameters, conditional-statements, type-inference

I created a [bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25444) for this, but perhaps someone has an idea for a workaround. Basically I want to have some arguments to a function based conditionally on the type of another:

```
declare function foo<P>(params: { f: (p: P) => void } & P): void;

foo({
  f(params: { bar(x: number): void }) {},
  bar(x) {},
});
```

So there is a special parameter `f` which has a function type, and whatever properties that function expects must be included as arguments to `foo`. Here again the parameter to `bar` is inferred as `any` but should be `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments the scenario is actually related to react components and the way the new generic component feature interacts with default generic parameters.

**The problem**

If we have a react component that has a generic parameter and the default value for the generic parameter has function field, the parameters to the function we pass in will not be inferred. A simple example would be:

```
  class Foo<P = { fn : (e: string)=> void }> extends React.Component<P>{}
  let foo = () => (
    <div>
      <Foo fn={e=> e}/> {/* e is any */}
    </div>
  )
```

**Possible solution**

Let me preface this with a caveat, I don't know it this works in all situations, or whether this depends on some compiler behavior that will change. What I did find is that it is a very fragile solution, change any detail, even with something that might reasonably be considered equivalent and it will not work. What I can say is that as presented it worked for what I tested it on.

The solution is to take advantage of the fact that the property types are taken from the return value of the constructor, and if we simplify things a little bit for the default generic parameter we get the inference we want. The only problem is detecting that we are dealing with the default generic parameter. We can do this by adding an extra field to the default parameter and then test for it using conditional types. Just one more caveat, this does not work for simple cases where `P` can be inferred based on used properties, so we will have an example where the component extracts properties from another component (which is actually closer to your use case):

```
// Do not change { __default?:true } to DefaultGenericParameter it only works with the former for some reason
type IfDefaultParameter<C, Default, NonDefault> = C extends { __default?:true } ? Default : NonDefault
type DefaultGenericParameter = { __default? : true; }

export type InferredProps<C extends React.ReactType> =
  C extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P :
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[C] :
  {};

// The props for Foo, will extract props from the generic parameter passed in 
type FooProps<T extends React.ReactType = React.ComponentClass<{ fn: (s: string )=> void }>> = InferredProps<T> & {
  other?: string
}

// Actual component class
class _Foo<P> extends React.Component<P>{}

// The public facing constructor 
const Foo : {
  new <P extends React.ReactType & {__default?: true} = React.ComponentClass<{ fn: (s: string )=> void }> & DefaultGenericParameter>(p: P) :
  IfDefaultParameter<P, _Foo<FooProps>, _Foo<FooProps<P>>>
} = _Foo as any;

  let foo = () => (
    <div>
      <Foo fn={e=> e}/> {/* e is string */}
      <Foo<React.ComponentClass<{ fn: (s: number )=> void }>> fn={e=> e}/> {/* e is number */}
    </div>
  )
```

**Applied in material ui**

The one sample I have tried in the material-ui repo is the `Avatar` component and it seems to work:

```
export type AvatarProps<C extends AnyComponent = AnyComponent> = StandardProps<
  PassthruProps<C, 'div'>,
  AvatarClassKey
> & {
  alt?: string;
  childrenClassName?: string;
  component?: C;
  imgProps?: React.HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>;
  sizes?: string;
  src?: string;
  srcSet?: string;
};

type IfDefaultParameter<C, Default, NonDefault> = C extends { __default?:true } ? Default : NonDefault
type DefaultGenericParameter = { __default? : true; }

declare const Avatar : {
  new <C extends AnyComponent & DefaultGenericParameter = 'div' & DefaultGenericParameter>(props: C) 
  : IfDefaultParameter<C, React.Component<AvatarProps<'div'>>, React.Component<AvatarProps<C>>>
}
```

Usage

```
const AvatarTest = () => (
  <div>
    {/* e is React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>*/}
    <Avatar onClick={e => log(e)} alt="Image Alt" src="example.jpg" />
    {/* e is {/* e is React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>*/}*/}
    <Avatar<'button'> onClick={e => log(e)} component="button" alt="Image Alt" src="example.jpg" />
    <Avatar<React.SFC<{ x: number }>>
      component={props => <div>{props.x}</div>} // props is props: {x: number;} & {children?: React.ReactNode;}
      x={3} // ok 
      // IS NOT allowed:
      // onClick={e => log(e)}
      alt="Image Alt"
      src="example.jpg"
    />
  </div>
```

Good luck with this, let me know if any of it helped. It was a fun little problem that has been keeping me awake for 10 days now :)

Comment: This looks promising in that it works for the default case and it allows specifying correct props explicitly in the override case. Unfortunately it seems like the inferred types of the extra props are no longer consistent with the `component` prop, if present. For example in `<Avatar onClick={e => log(e)} component="button" />` (no generic provided), the type of `e` is inferred incorrectly as `React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>`. As long as you remember that you must provide a generic if you provide the `component` prop though, it seems to work.

Comment: The bounty is about to expire and this is the best answer I've seen, so I'm gonna give it to you :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah you are right, the case when you specify button but don't specify a type parameter should at least be an error. I will see if I can get it to work that way tomorrow.

Comment: @TomCrockett changed the default props to be `React.Component<AvatarProps<'div'>>` instead of `React.Component<AvatarProps>` and now we get an error if `component` is something set wihout a type parameter. The inconsistency is caused by the way `AvatarProps` the default of `div` is specified in `AvatarProps` not by this solution necessarily.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I see a requirement to have function type that depends on argument values, "use overloads" is the first thing that comes to mind:

```
declare function foo(params: { tag: 'a', bar(x: number): void }): void;
declare function foo(params: { tag: 'b', bar(x: boolean): void }): void;

foo({ tag: 'a', bar(x) { console.log('x =', x)} }); // (parameter) x: number
```

**Update** I assume that in the following code `foo` and `f` are React components, and `foo` exposes `f` as its property, as well as all the properties that `f` has.

```
declare function foo<P>(params: { f: (p: P) => void } & P): void;

foo({
  f(params: { bar(x: number): void }) {},
  bar(x) {},
});
```

There is a way to rewrite it, it you don't insist that the name of `f` (which is a property of `foo`), as well as types of `f` properties must be declared inline within `foo` arguments when calling it.

You can declare a type that describes properties of such composed component, it takes two generic parameters: the type of inner component properties, and the name of inner component in outer properties:

```
type ComposedProps<InnerProps, N extends string> = 
       InnerProps & { [n in N]: (props: InnerProps) => void };  

// Also I assume in reality it does not return `void` but `React.Element`,
//  but I don't think it matters

declare function foo<P>(params: P): void;

// foo generic parameter is given explicitly,
//  which allows to infer (and not repeat) parameter types for `f` and `bar` 
foo<ComposedProps<{bar(x: number): void}, 'f'>>({
  f(params) {}, // params: { bar(x: number): void; }
  bar(x) {}, // (parameter) x: number
});
```

Comment: I've edited my question to add a more realistic example where the set of overloads would be unbounded.

Comment: @TomCrockett The problem with your edited version is that the object literal type references itself and the compiler has a limitation in inferring such a recursive structure (at least as far as I can tell) Is this the real thing you are trying to model ? or is this also a more or less acurate approximation (even small differences may make the difference between possible and imposible, you are at the outer limits of the type system :) )

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, this is closer to the real problem. If you're interested, the full real problem is defining accurate typings for Material UI, many of whose components follow a pattern of allowing a `component` override prop, to which any "extra" props on the outer component will be spread. See for example https://material-ui.com/api/button/. I realize it may be beyond what the type system can handle, but figured it couldn't hurt to ask :)

Comment: @TomCrockett I can't say I have worked with MaterialUI so this is a bit alien to me, There may be things we can do around the type of `this` within such methods. Ex: `function foo<T>(foo: T & ThisType<T & { default : number }>) { }

foo({
    customValue: 10,
    method() { this.customValue + this.default }
})` but without a minimal working sample I can't tell if this helps.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir there's a PR with more details about the real use case if you're curious: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/11731

Comment: @TomCrockett Yeah .. I looked at it.. it's a fun little problem, I have some interesting findings but no solutions unfortunately, see your gitter I  wrote to you there, maybe it helps :)

Comment: @artem thanks for your update, and yes `foo` and `f` are react components. We really want to avoid having to provide a type argument to the outer component, and instead have it infer the type of the inner component and therefore the types of the additional props. There's also the complication that the `component` prop (i.e. `f` in this example) is optional, and should default to some _particular_ component with a particular set of additional props. E.g. in the case of `Button`, when `component` is not provided defaults to `button`, which means all the standard props of a `button` can be used